# Issues adding labels to mosaic3d plot in r

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

I am able to see labels if I use the simple 2d mosaic() function based on this example below.

```
labs <- round(prop.table(Titanic), 2)
mosaic(Titanic, pop = FALSE)
labeling_cells(text = labs, margin = 0)(Titanic)
```

However if i try to change this to `mosaic3d` then all the labels disappear and i see some black dots. Any help on how to add labels to mosaic3d plot is much appreciated.

Comment: The black dots are not meant to replace the labels. You need to say what you are trying to achieve. Labeling rgl plots has its difficulties.

Comment: @42- I agree, i am just trying to find out how to get the label function to work within the `mosaic3d` function similar to how it works within the vanilla 2d `mosaic` function using the Titanic dataset.